# How use proxyAgent only in development env

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, https-proxy-agent

I´m currently forced to comment or uncomment a single line in my request object, depending if my application currently run my local system or the productive server.

I already tried to solve this problem with a bool variable, but it does not work. Here is my Code

```
const dev = true;
const devProxy = dev
  ? {agent: new HttpsProxyAgent("http://proxy:80")}
  : {};

 myFunc: async access_token => {
    const response = await fetch(
      URL,
      {
        // agent: new HttpsProxyAgent("http://proxy:89´0"),
        devProxy,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token.access_token}`
        }
      }
    );
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
    }
    throw new Error(
      "bla" +
        response.status +
        " StatusText: " +
        response.statusText
    );
  },
```

The error says that the proxy was not used.

How can I correctly do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple things you can do, can isolate the object to another variable and set the agent. OR you can `Object.assign` the `agent` key as well.
Simplest would be assigning a variable:

```
const dev = true;
const options = {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token.access_token}`
  }
}
if (dev) options.agent = new HttpsProxyAgent("http://proxy:80");

myFunc: async access_token => {
  const response = await fetch(
    URL,
    options
  );
  if (response.ok) {
    return response.json();
  }
  throw new Error(
    "bla" +
    response.status +
    " StatusText: " +
    response.statusText
  );
},
```